# How do you configure WebMatrix to run PHP on *.htm, *.html files?

Tags: php, webmatrix, iis-express

I'm running a PHP website locally using WebMatrix. This site uses PHP within *.html files. By default, WebMatrix doesn't allow this. How do I configure WebMatrix so that the PHP runs?

(note that I'm answering my own question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit the file:

```
%USERPROFILE%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config
```

(For example, "C:\Users\Marcus\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config")

You'll notice a line like this:

```
<add name="PHP53_via_FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v5.3\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" />
```

You can add other file extensions by adding new lines:

```
<add name="PHP53_via_FastCGI_html" path="*.html" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v5.3\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" />
<add name="PHP53_via_FastCGI_htm" path="*.htm" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v5.3\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" />
```

It's important that you give each <add /> element a unique 'name' attribute.

Comment: (If anyone is reading this and has a better solution, please do tell! After a couple tries, I couldn't figure out a syntax that would let me do this all within a single element (e.g. "*.php,*.htm,*.html"))

Comment: Ignore the italics in the last comment. I wanted actual asterisks on both sides of ".php,"